# Unexpected pylance behaviour with Django vscode

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, ide, pylance

I have Django project written with VScode
When I open it on another machine I'm starting to receive errors from pylance. I compared all settings.

Example of mistake:
`"user" is not a known member of "None"`
`"GET" is not a known member of "None"`
`"ingredient" is possibly unbound`

All the packages from requirements.txt, the same version of python as original etc.

screenshot

[image: 1]

I've reinstalled IDE, python and extensions. It didn't work, so I have no idea what's the reason.

Comment: That might be due to this setting: "python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "strict". I was trying to add type checking to my django project as well but I think the problem comes from the fact that Django is not a static typed Framework.  This [article](https://dev.to/jodaut/python-type-checking-with-visual-studio-code-46a7) mentions how to do it using mypy in vscode and it works by silencing a lot of errors.

Answer (score 0):

Are the two machines the same version of the extension? Please make sure to install the latest version of ***Pylance***.

You can also ignore these errors using the following configuration.

```json
    "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
        "reportOptionalMemberAccess": "none",
        "reportUnboundVariable": "none"
    },
```

Comment: Thanks,
Yeah, I'm using the latest Pylance on both of machines

And about ignoring mistakes. I don't think that it will help, because in every file of my project I have different types of mistakes.
For example, 
`Cannot access member "model" for type "FavoriteAndCartViewSet"
  Member "model" is unknown`

Comment: So, probably pylance just don't understand that I'm workning with Django, or some PATHes missing, or something else.

Comment: This [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django) may help.

Comment: I've tried to make it duriung official insuractions, but didn't help(

Comment: Please check in detail the different configurations that exist on the two machines. Check that there are those different settings in settings.json.